# How to bind server actions api data in jsx in next.js 13.4

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a server component in next.js 13.4 and on first load I am calling an api to get the data of weather, it is working fine.

Now I want to change the city using a form input. Which I am doing using server actions. But how to update the data of local variable `weatherData` to UI is update with new weather data?

```
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

async function getWeatherData(address) {
  const weatherData = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/weather?address=" + address,
    { cache: "no-cache", tags: ["weather"] }
  );
  if (!weatherData.ok) return notFound();
  return weatherData.json();
}

const Home = async () => {
  const weatherData = (await getWeatherData("lahore")).data;
  // console.log(weatherData);

  async function changeCityAction(data) {
    "use server";
    const city = data.get("cityName")?.toString();
    const weatherData = (await getWeatherData(city)).data;
    console.log(weatherData);
    // Here, how to update UI with this new data
    revalidatePath("/weather");
  }
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <article className={styles.widget}>
        <form className={styles.weatherLocation} action={changeCityAction}>
          <input
            className={styles.input_field}
            placeholder="Enter city name"
            type="text"
            id="cityName"
            name="cityName"
          />
          <button className={styles.search_button} type="submit">
            Seach
          </button>
        </form>
        <div className={styles.icon_and_weatherInfo}>
          <div className={styles.weatherIcon}>
            {weatherData?.weather[0]?.description === "rain" ||
            weatherData?.weather[0]?.description === "fog" ? (
              <i
                className={`wi wi-day-${weatherData?.weather[0]?.description}`}
              ></i>
            ) : (
              <i className="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={styles.weatherInfo}>
            <div className={styles.temperature}>
              <span>
                {(weatherData?.main?.temp - 273.5).toFixed(2) +
                  String.fromCharCode(176)}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.weatherCondition}>
              {weatherData?.weather[0]?.description?.toUpperCase()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.place}>{weatherData?.name}</div>
      </article>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Server Component can have updating process itself since its purposes are to decrease browsers side burdens. If you want to add re-render and UI updating, [you should combine Client Component and Server Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#with-client-components). As you know, Client Component can have hooks like useState which fires re-render and you can see UI updating.

[Here is when to use Server Component.](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components)